# how to append the value from picker to textfield

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am having a picker, which displays data from 2 arrays, say like it is a picker with 2 sections.
Now I want the selected values from both the sections, to appear in a single `textfield`.

I tried with

```
textField.text=[[First_Array ObjectAtindex:row]appendString:[Second_Array ObjectAtIndex:row]];
```

But it gives error “Void Value not ignored as it ought yo be”

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `appendString:`, use `stringByAppendingString:`. `appendString:` is used to modify an `NSMutableString` in place, it doesn't return a value.